# Create Simple qml application

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qml, qt4.6

I am new to Qt. I am creating simple qml application.
Qt Version :- QMake version 2.01a
              Using Qt version 4.6.2 
I am on Linux system.
I have created qml containing two buttons(button.qml) and also created c++ code(main.cpp).

Code for main.cpp

```
 #include<QtGui/QApplication>
 #include<QtGui/QLabel>
 #include"qmlapplicationviewer.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QmlApplicationViewer viewer;

    viewer.setOrientation(QmlApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationLockLandscape);   
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QLatin1String("button.qml"));
    viewer.showExpanded();
    a.exec();
}
```

I am compiling it with `qmake && make` and got error as

```
qmlapplicationviewer.h: No such file or directory
QmlApplicationViewerâ was not declared in this scope
```

I tried to search for "qmlapplicationviewer.h" and "QmlApplicationViewer" on my system.
But unable to find it.

Please help.

Comment: Qt 4.6.2? QML was added in 4.7!

Comment: @Laszlo: thanks.That means i need to install latest version.

Comment: Not the latest, but at least a newer version unless you use the separate qml package from pre-historic time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use the application viewer for such a simple case, so I would drop it. I would write something like this:

```
#include <QDeclarativeView>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    QDeclarativeView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl("button.qml"));
    view.showFullScreen();

    return app.exec();
}
```

If you really wish to use the qml application viewer, you could obtain the header and source file from [here](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/85601df1af37ccc9d3b8d3942853ec2a82e15c2d%3aexamples/helper/qmlapplicationviewer), and add them to the corresponding `HEADERS` and `SOURCES` variables in your project file.

Comment: I had same issue with QDeclarativeView

fatal error: QDeclarativeView: No such file or directory. I'm using Qt 5.4.0